# How can elements of ObservableCollection which are directly bound be notified

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have an `ObservableCollection<Data>`, and each `Data` object is directly bound to an UIElement in the following fashion:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `Data` object is a very big object, and contains a lot of attributes. I implemented a converter to convert it into a canvas element to render.

Now, the problem is that when the property of `Data` is changed, it would not notify `Data` object, and thus the UI would not change. I am thinking whether there is an elegant way to solve this problem.

```cs
public class SomeDataObject : NotifyObject // implements INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _a;

    // now `a` is changed
    public int a
    {
        get => _a;
        set => SetProperty(ref _a, value);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: You may perhaps use a MultiBinding that binds to the `a` property and to the SomeDataObject instance.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks. Well, I know this method, but as I mentioned `SomeDataObject` is a very large class, as the codebase develops, there are a properties in `SomeDataObject`, and the MultiBinding would use increasing amount of parameter.

Comment: No, the MultiBinding would have exactly two Bindings, one for `a` and one for the data item itself. Whenever anything changes in the data item, fire the change notification of `a` and thus trigger the Binding and the MultiBinding. Or add some other dummy property. Just make sure the property returns different values whenever its change notification has been fired.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks! That perfectly fulfill my needs.